# iBeacon利用アプリでUIBackgroundModesにlocationを指定するとリジェクト

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, appstore-approval

iBeaconをバックグラウンドで検出してLocalNotificationを発行するアプリを開発し、
App Storeで公開しようとしています。

しかしながらiTunes Connectでバイナリを審査に出すと、

> 2.16 - Multitasking Apps may only use background services for their intended purposes: VoIP, audio playback, location, task completion, local notifications, etc.

という理由からリジェクトされてしまいます。内容としては

> Your app declares support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file but does not declare any features that require persistent location. Apps that declare support for location in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist file must have features that require persistent location.
>   Specifically, it is not appropriate and not necessary to use the location background mode for iBeacon detections.

となり、iBeaconの検出にUIBackgroundModesのlocationキーの定義は不要で継続的な
位置情報を必要とする機能もアプリ内には見当たらないという内容でした。

ただアプリからUIBackgroundModesのlocationキーを外してしまうと、バックグラウンド
時のレンジングが全く動作せずフォアグラウンド時のみしかiBeaconの検出ができません。
Minor IDが異なる複数のiBeaconが存在する場所で、レンジング中に一番近くにある
Beaconを選択して処理するためMinor IDを取得できないdidEnterRegion内では処理する
ことができないです。アプリがバックグラウンドでiBeaconを受信してLocalNotification
が表示される様子については審査の際に動画を送っているのですが・・・。

UIBackgroundModesのlocationキーを定義せずバックグラウンドでiBeaconのレンジング
を継続する実装方法か、該当機能に継続的な位置情報が必要だとうまく説明する方法を
教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず始めにiOSアプリでは、UIBackgroundModesでlocationをセットするか否かに関わらず、Background起動時での継続的なレンジングはできません。
(ただし、約10秒間は動作します。)
iBeaconのモニタリングは上記の設定に関わらずBackgroundでもアプリ停止時でも可能です。
レンジングはモニタリングに比べて消費電力が多くなるため、Apple側が制限をかけていると思われます。

もし、Background起動時でも、ある程度の時間、レンジングをしたいということであれば、UIBackgroundTaskを利用する方法があります。
ただし、最長で約3分間の起動です。
(3分を超えてレンジングし続けることはできません。)
参考:
[バックグラウンドで継続して処理を実施する](http://qiita.com/edo_m18/items/52fb7190d4285aabc1c9)

少しでも参考になれば幸いです。

Comment: 現状としてはlocationキーをセットすると、アプリがフォアグラウンドに
ない時でも継続してレンジングが実施できていましたので、実際は
バックグラウンド状態ではないのかもしれません。

最長3分間しかレンジングが継続できないとなると、Beaconが複数
設置されていてdidExitRegionが呼ばれない環境だと移動に合わせて
近いBeaconに合わせたLocalNotificationを打っていく、現状の仕様が
満足できなさそうで大規模な修正が必要になるのかなと感じています。

Comment: Backgroundで常にiBeaconのレンジングは難しいですが、例えば、NSTimerと位置情報サービスを組み合わせてみる方法はいかがでしょうか？
iOSでは通常、NSTimerをBackgroundで動かすことはできないのですが、位置情報サービスを組み合わせることで可能になります。
この定期間隔処理でiBeaconのレンジング開始/停止を繰り返せば、定期間隔でのレンジングができるかもしれません。
領域を出てからdidExitRegionが呼ばれるまでに約20〜30秒程度かかると思うので、間隔の指定には注意が必要だと思います。
NSTimerと位置情報サービスについては、
http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2013/09/27/location-nstimer/
が参考になるかと思います。

要件にふさわしいかどうかわからないのですが、参考までに。

Comment: NSTimerで定周期処理でレンジングを繰り返し行う方法もあるのですね。ただUIBackgroundModesにlocationキーを指定する必要があるようなので、やはりApp Review Teamに粘り強くlocationキーの必要性を説明する必要がありそうです。Contact the App Review Teamからlocationキーを必要とする機能の詳細を説明してみようと思います。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 他のBeacon対応アプリの説明欄を参考にして、バックグラウンドの位置情報を使う機能と制限事項（消費電力）について説明を書き直しレビューアー向けの説明も同様にしたところ、無事審査を通過できました。